# Gnome screen sharing fails in extend mode

Tags: gnome

I excitedly discovered through some reddit post that gnome since version 42 supports screen sharing via RDP. I could succesfully try it out in the `mirror-primary` mode. However as soon as I switch to `extend` mode my android tablet fails to connect. How can I debug this issue?

I am running GNOME Shell 43.1 and

```
$echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```